# Finding longPress release Location

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, cgpoint, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I'm Using LongPress on control and drag different positions in views. I found out the starting position using UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan. how do i found out the UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{
            CGPoint center = snapshot.center;
            center.y = location.y;
            snapshot.center = center;
}
if (UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
{
     location = [longPress locationInView:self.tableView];
}
```